# adding values to a different column after button click

Tags: php, html, mysql, database, phpmyadmin

I have a page where users can view the tickets they sent, they can cancel it as well, here's what it looks like:

[image]

What I want to happen is that when I click on the "Closed: Cancelled" button. It would show "Closed: Cancelled" in the assignee column as well. Currently this is what I only get when I click the button:

[image]

Here's my form:

```html
<div class="container">
<div class="page-header">
<h3>My Tickets</h3>
   <div class="table-responsive">
    <table class="table">
     <tr>
      <th>Employee Name</th>
      <th>Time</th>
      <th>Priority</th>
      <th>Assignee</th>
      <th>Subject</th>
      <th>Problem</th>
      <th>Status</th>
      <th></th>
     </tr>
    <?php
     include ('database.php');
     $result = $database->prepare ("SELECT tickets.* FROM tickets INNER JOIN employee ON employee.id = tickets.employee_id WHERE employee.username = '".$_SESSION["VALID_USER_ID"]."'");
     $result ->execute();
     for ($count=0; $row_message = $result ->fetch(); $count++){
    ?>
     <tr>
      <td><?php echo $row_message['firstname']." ".$row_message['lastname']; ?></td>
      <td><?php echo $row_message['time']; ?></td>
      <td><?php echo $row_message['priority']; ?></td>
      <td><?php echo $row_message['assignee']; ?></td>
      <td><?php echo $row_message['subject']; ?></td>
      <td><?php echo $row_message['problem']; ?></td>
      <?php if ($row_message['status']) : ?>
      <td><?php echo $row_message['status']."".$row_message['assignee'];?></td>
      <?php else : ?>
      <td>
       <form method="post" action="update-ticket-status-emp.php">
        <input type="hidden" name="ticketno" value="<?php echo $row_message['ticketno']; ?>" />
        <input type="submit" name="closedcan" value="Closed: Cancelled"></input>
       </form>
      </td>
      <?php endif ; ?>
     </tr>
     <?php } ?>
     
     </table>
     
     <a href="employee_panel.php"><button type="button" class="btn btn-primary"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-arrow-left"></i> Back</button></a> 
    </div>
   </div>
  </div> 
 </div>
</div>
```

And here's the exec code:

```js
<?php

   if(isset($_POST['closedcan']))
    {
        $msg = "ClosedCan";
        $status = $_POST['closedcan'];
  $assignee = $_POST['closedcan'];
    }

    $ticketno=$_POST['ticketno'];
    $con = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', '');
    mysqli_select_db($con, 'companydb');

    $sql = "UPDATE tickets SET status = '$status' WHERE ticketno = '$ticketno'";

    if(mysqli_query($con, $sql))
        header("refresh:1; url=view-tickets-emp.php?msg=$msg");
    else
        var_dump(mysqli_error($con));
 
?>
```

PS: I know mysql is deprecated, I will change it eventually when I figure this out.

Comment: FYI, it is possible to have a syntax-error-free `UPDATE` that does not actually UPDATE.  Your code does not realize this.  Also, your UPDATE query is vulnerable to injection attacks.  Please implement prepared statements with placeholders.  Are you using pdo on one file and mysqli on another?  `mysqli_` is not deprecated, `mysql_` is.  Please reduce the tabbing in your code block and do not use "runnable" code blocks unless the script is "runnable".

Answer (score 0):

Modified the query in the exec code:

```js
$sql = "UPDATE tickets SET status = '$status', assignee = '$assignee' WHERE ticketno = '$ticketno'";
```